# How do I implement a premade node.js module into my android application?

Tags: android, node.js, bluetooth, server

I am trying to write an alternate android app to manage the pavlok bluetooth device. The company that manufactures the device have publicly released an api to encourage development for it. It can be found here: https://github.com/Behavioral-Technology-Group/Pavlok_Node_Module The API is a node requiring the installation with node.js to run. I have no idea how to do this within the bounds of my android app

Comment: Are you asking how to write Javascript for an Android app? If so, that's too broad to answer here

Comment: No, I'm basically asking how to run node.js systems in Android.

Comment: Not possible, sorry... there are alternative Javascript frameworks for writing Android apps. I don't see why you are limiting yourself to "Node.js"